# Red5 demo how to tell if its working?

Tags: video-streaming, port, vps, red5, http-live-streaming

My problem is that I installed Red5 media server on my VPS; But when I try to see if it is working or not using the demo I see this output:

```
(1179) Connections: true | true
(3745) connected?: true
(8983) NetConnection.onStatus: 
level = error
code = NetConnection.Connect.Failed
```

(OflaDemo output)

If you want to try and see the problem also: http://elearningau.com:5080 and launch Demo.
I tried OflaDemo & shared ball.(P.S. we installed also OflaDemo and SOSample on our VPS)

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna check the address in address bar next to the red5 logo.

Change it to "rmtp://yourservernameorip/oflaDemo" because by default, it points to localhost

Answer (score 1):

Replace the "rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo" in the oflaDemo with "rtmp://elearningau.com/oflaDemo" and it should work.

Comment: thanks. I tried it but again I took error message:
(286) Connections: true | true ;
(16361) connected?: true ;
(16878) NetConnection.onStatus: ; 
  description = No scope 'oflaDemo' on this server. ;
  code = NetConnection.Connect.Rejected ;
  level = error ;


(16879) NetConnection.onStatus: ; 
  level = status ;
  code = NetConnection.Connect.Closed ;

Comment: You also need to have the oflaDemo installed

Comment: Did you edit the red5-web.properties at all? If you haven't, you might want to set the virtual hosts to *

Comment: That error means that the oflademo app didn't start, there should be something in the red5.log

Comment: The problem may also be that port 1935 is not open on your vps firewall; that is REQUIRED for flash to work.